# multiple time series prediction with VAR

Tags: time-series, prediction, vector-autoregression, arma

I have a time slot like 2-3 pm everyday when a series of events occur. These events occur in different frequencies on different time e.g. some times twice a second, sometime once every 10 seconds. I am summing up their occurrences against a minute. So for each day I have a set of 60 discrete values.

There can be some seasonal behavior in these series like less occurrences near 2:10 - 2:20 pm and high occurrences near 2:30 - 2:40 pm. However there may be a trend of forward movement of this sub slots e.g. 2:10 is moving by 1 minute each day or some thing like that.

after `k` days have past I want to predict the occurrences on 2-3 pm of `k+1` th day. So if I model it looks like

$$ 
\begin{bmatrix}
    y_{1} \\
    y_{2} \\
    \vdots \\
    y_{k}
\end{bmatrix}
=
\begin{bmatrix}
    x_{11} & x_{12} & x_{13} & \dots  & x_{1n} \\
    x_{21} & x_{22} & x_{23} & \dots  & x_{2n} \\
    \vdots & \vdots & \vdots & \ddots & \vdots \\
    x_{k1} & x_{k2} & x_{k3} & \dots  & x_{kn}
\end{bmatrix}
$$
$ y_{i} $ is the univariate time series for $i^{th}$ day. And $x_{ij}$ is the occurrences of $j^{th}$ minute of $ i^{th} $ day. $n=60$ . I want to predict $ y_{k+1} $

What method should I use ? should I use `VAR` or `ARMA` ? It looks like I need to observe $x_{i1} \dots x_{ki} $ and predict $ x_{k+1, i}$, and iterate this process $ n $ times to predict $ x_{l+1, n} $, am I right till this ? I am not understanding the process. It looks like first I need to subtract the mean from each $x_{ij}$ to make it `zero-mean`. I am stuck on how to calculate `acf` and `pacf`

Is there any easy step by step guide ?